# Why AVPlayer ask several union range in same session?

Tags: ios, stream, http-headers, avplayer

I'm would to know why AVPlayer ask's 
union ranges in requests.
Example:
1. We have good wi-fi connection.
2. Track with total length = 1000000.

AVPlayer in first will ask `bytes=0-1` - its ok, it just "ping" the availability of track.

But after that it will ask `bytes=0-999999` - and get `content-len 1000000`;

And after that it will ask `bytes=40000-999999` - and get `content-len 599999`;

Why it make third request if we must have all data from second request (bytes=0-999999)?

Comment: I have a similar question:  why does AVPlayer not ask a smaller range in the second request?  Isn't the whole point of `range` is to ask for only partial content?